# UIButton in collectionView doesn't retain highlighting

Tags: xcode

I have a collectionView, full of cells with a single button in each.  I have a custom class for the cell.  When I press a button, it highlights, and then quickly reverts to normal (in maybe 0.5-1seconds.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    GridControlViewOutputCell * outputCell;
    outputCell = (GridControlViewOutputCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"gridControlViewOutputCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(outputCell == nil)
    {
        outputCell = [[GridControlViewOutputCell alloc] init];
    }
    outputCell.outputDelegate = self;
    outputCell.ioIndex = indexPath.row;
    [outputCell.outputButton setUserInteractionEnabled:true];
    [outputCell.outputButton setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:true];
    [outputCell.outputButton setAdjustsImageWhenDisabled:true];
    [outputCell.outputButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [outputCell.outputButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_normal.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:12] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [outputCell.outputButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_pressed.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:12] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    if([buttons count] > indexPath.row)
    {
        [buttons replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:outputCell.outputButton];
    }
    else{
        [buttons insertObject:outputCell.outputButton atIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    return outputCell;
}

#import "GridControlViewOutputCell.h"

@implementation GridControlViewOutputCell
@synthesize outputDelegate;
@synthesize ioIndex;
@synthesize outputButton;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    return self;
}

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [outputDelegate outputChanged:ioIndex on:true];
}

-(IBAction)buttonReleased:(id)sender
{
    [outputDelegate outputChanged:ioIndex on:false];
}

@end
```

buttonPressed is tied to touchdown

buttonReleased is tied to touch cancel, drag exit, touch up inside (although i am not sure i need touch cancel)

the events fire as expected, it's just the highlighting doesn't "stick" when the button is held.

EDIT: just to be clear, I'm not trying to keep the button highlighted after releasing it.  there are several questions on here relating to that.  I'm just trying to keep it highlighted while it is pressed.